# Android Volley JsonRequest receiving the wrong return

Tags: android, json, request, android-volley

After make a request the volley listener called is onErrorResponse and for my surprise the error message is the callback that I wanted from my server, a json with correct datas.

What is strange thats a parseError but how's a parse error if I make the parse in the onResponse listener.

I'm new in android.

My method:

```
public void getAllEstablishmentsRequest(){

    String url = "http://myServer.com/something";

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                        JSONArray Jarray = object.getJSONArray("data");

                        for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e){
                        Log.e("Volley", "Error JSON");
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    Log.e("Volley", "Error - requisição das campanhas de Eutrofização");
                    System.out.println(error);
                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Error: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value {"data":{"establishments":[{"created_by":1,"phone":"(85) 3246-3834","teste":1453583589,"neighborhood":"Joaquim Távora","last_promotion":"2015-10-06 12:42:01","days_last_promotion":110,"id":2,"distance":0,"updated_at":"2015-10-06 12:42:01","address":"Av. Barão de Studart, 2675","name":"São Luiz","updated_by":1,"created_at":"2015-05-31 19:48:58","active":true,"longitude":"-38.510342","latitude":"-3.746922"},{"created_by":3,"phone":"(85) 4008-2444","teste":1453583589,"neighborhood":"Messejana","last_promotion":"2016-01-22 13:45:30","days_last_promotion":2,"id":96,"distance":0,"updated_at":"2016-01-22 13:45:30","address":"Av. Frei Cirilo, 4290","name":"Pinheiro","updated_by":3,"created_at":"2015-12-24 14:27:29","active":true,"longitude":"-38.495841","latitude":"-3.821112"},{"created_by":3,"phone":"","teste":1453583589,"neighborhood":"Vila Peri","last_promotion":"2016-01-21 19:06:16","days_last_promotion":2,"id":140,"distance":0,"updated_at":"2016-01-21 19:06:16","address":"Rua Cônego de Castro, 3859","name":"Cometa","updated_by":null,"created_at":"2016-01-21 18:21:41","active":true,"longitude":"-38.587981","latitude":"-3.800781"}],"establishments_total":134},"success":"YES","time":"2016-01-23 18:13:09"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `JsonArrayRequest` when you are getting a JsonObject as a response from the server. Use `JsonObjectRequest` instead. Something like this:

```
public void getAllEstablishmentsRequest(){

   String url = "http://myServer.com/something";

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject object) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray Jarray = object.getJSONArray("data");

                        for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e){
                        Log.e("Volley", "Error JSON");
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    Log.e("Volley", "Error - requisição das campanhas de Eutrofização");
                    System.out.println(error);
                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```